# How to find receiver mail address in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Im writing code for receiving mail and convert to ticket. I assign randomnumber@appid.appspotmail.com to agent. when I get mail find receive mail address, assign to that agent. but I dont know how to receiver mail address so that I find the random number and find agent.

Please do the needful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read: ["Handling Incoming Email"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving)

> Call getFrom() to return the sender of the message.

Comment: Asked receiver mail id(get toaddress)

Comment: Missed that, use getRecipients()  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType)